# vector of class that inherits from class template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, inheritance

I have a template class like this

```
template <class DatasetType>
class DataHandler
{
    void Action(DatasetType* Test)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

and then I need to store in an array this template class

```
class Factory{
    vector<DataHandler<BaseData>*> availableData;
    void SetAvailableData(vector<DataHandler<BaseData>*> i_availableData)
    {
    this->availableData= i_availableData;
    }
}
```

BaseData is a base class

```
class BaseData
{
virtual void HandleData() = 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I try to put something in the array that is inherit of BaseData

```
class DataType1: public BaseData 
{
void HandleData() override;
}
```

...

```
vector<DataHandler<DataType1>*> arrayWithData = vector<DataHandler<DataType1>*>();
factory->SetAvailableData(arrayWithData );
```

...

> Error E0312 "no suitable user-defined conversion from std::vector < DataHandler < DataType1 > * > to std::vector < DataHandler < BaseData > * >

I thought that the very reason to use inherit was that no conversion would be needed. In an array of BaseData[] I could store DataType1?
DataHandler needs to be able to 'handle' any data type,
but in this specific situation Factory needs to be able to store everything that inherits from only BaseData.
What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

-edit-

ok basically what I want is that DataHandler is only a base class, and I need to create different DataHandlers that inherits from this base class.

BaseData contains basic operations with generic data, and I need to create other data types that inherits from BaseData

My original problem was that when I want to use DataHandler I used it as such

```
DataType1* dataType = new DataType1();
handler->Start(dataType);


void DataHandler2::Start(DataBase* data)

     { 
    DataType1* newData= dynamic_cast<DataType1*>(data);
    }
```

in my handler I always had to do dynamic casts, and it looked really bad that I had to do dynamic casts in every function of DataHandlers
I tried to solve this with the use of class template

Comment: *"In an array of BaseData[] I could store DataType1?"* - No. You can only store `BaseData` in an array of `BaseData`.

Comment: am I confusing this with something else? I was positive that that was how polymorphism worked

Comment: Run-time polymorphism in C++ works with pointers or references.

Comment: What is `DataHandler` supposed to do with `DatasetType` other than define that member function?

Comment: Factory works with DataHandler and all that inherits from DataHandler
My problem was that I needed to do dynamic casting all the time

```void DataHandler2::Start(DataBase* data)
{
 DataType1* newData= dynamic_cast<DataType1*>(data);
}```

so I thought to add what type it handles by using class template in DataHandler
DataHandler2 inherits from DataHandler

Comment: clarifications: the factory that works with DataType1 has a vector of DataType1 and handles them such, and never handles with any other data types

Comment: Vectors that store different types are unrelated and incompatible, even if the stored types are themselves related. In your case the stored types are unrelated and incompatible too, because they are pointers to unrelated and incompatible types.

Comment: Perhaps the solution of your problem depends on what exactly you are doing inside `Action` and what other things you have in `DataHandler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `DataType1` inherits from `BaseData` (and pointers and references from the former can implicitly be converted to pointers and references to the latter), `DataHandler<DataType1>` and `DataHandler<BaseData>` are unrelated types.

You cannot convert a `DataHandler<BaseData>` to/from a `DataHandler<DataType1>` without providing a user-defined conversion. Once this is done, since you cannot define a conversion from/to `std::vector<DataHandler<BaseData>>` to/from `std::vector<DataHandler<DataType1>>`, you need to write a conversion function for this last step.